# App has not changed, IT group did a lot of "stuff" app works fine, except all Jquery Ajax calls never return

Tags: c#, json, jquery

Here's the situation.

.Net c# App has not changed, IT group did "a lot of stuff" (new san, new routers & switches software, etc) app works fine, except all Jquery Ajax calls never return.

So obviously they changed something...   In Dev tools in Chrome, I see the request go out, but it never receives a reply.

the server gets crippled by the pile up of hung threads, performance suffers horribly.
after 10k connections they have to bounce the server.

So of course now they want us to help them figure out what they did wrong.

What should I be looking for? My best guess is the wireshark the process and see where the last communications takes place.

after that I'm at a loss; what can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If the server configuration has not changed, then I would look at firewall settings. Wireshark is an excellent tool - can the server send data out over port 80? Can the server send ANYTHING out over the wire? The server is receiving something obviously otherwise you wouldn't have all these connections. I know for Sonicwall firewalls, outbound access is wide open by default but I believe that Cisco ASAs require explicit permission (not positive on this). Are you using VLANs? If so, is the server blocked from the outside world while being tucked in its own lonely VLAN? Also, run netstat -a on the server to check the connections to help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into those. Non ajax queries to the DB work fine, pages that don't use ajax work fine(login etc).. just the ajax calls don't work...